# How can I save my photo that is taken from form ImageField in database

Tags: django, image, forms

#models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/photos/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.photo}, {self.name}'
```

#admin.py

```
@admin.register(Contact)
class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'name', 'photo']
```

#forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Name')
    photo = forms.ImageField(required=False, label='Photo')
```

#views.py

```
def post(self, request:HttpRequest)->HttpResponse:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Contact.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data['name'], photo=form.cleaned_data['photo']).save()
```

And then when I've created contact with that photo, there's name but no src of photo in admin panel. It seems like it haven't been saved.

What could be the problem of that..?

Comment: pass request.FILES as documented https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads

Answer (score 0):

Update your HTML template to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag. This attribute is necessary for transmitting file data.

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- Your form fields here -->
</form>
```

In your Django view, when handling form submissions, access the uploaded file data using `request.FILES` instead of just `request.POST`.

```py
def post(self, request: HttpRequest) -> HttpResponse:
    form = ContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    # the rest of the code
```

By using `request.FILES`, you ensure that file data is properly transmitted and received by Django.